# Синхронная работа кода NodeJS

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise, callback

Потребовалось переписать программу на NodeJS, раньше реализовывал её на php, и java. И столкнулся с тем что выполнение import_to_json() выполняется раньше чем заканчивают свое выполнение функции перед ним. Поиски в интернете привели к промисам, к async await, к then(), к callback. Честно говоря очень запутался и с ходу не понял какой из способов подойдет и как его реализовать(перепробовал все из них, но ничего не вышло). Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так, что бы import_to_json() выполнился после того как выполнятся get_average_price_per_tm.update_average_price_per_tm() и get_current_price_per_tm.update_current_price_per_tm();(в этих методах происходит запрос к БД и так же api запросы, один выполняется 5 минут, другой 10) Круто что выполнение этих двух методов происходит асинхронно *как я понял*, но именно выполнение import_to_json() должно быть после того как выполнятся эти два метода.

```
function update_table(second_db) {
    work_with_db.connect_to_db(second_db);
    get_average_price_per_tm.update_average_price_per_tm(second_db);
    get_current_price_per_tm.update_current_price_per_tm(second_db);
    import_to_json(second_db);
}
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью `Promise.all` можно запустить несколько проммисов параллельно и дождаться пока они выполнятся.

В переменной `.then(res => ... )` будет результат выполнения двух функций (`get_avg_value`, `get_another_value`) в виде массива.

А такие слова, как `async/await` - просто удобный способ записывать конструкции типа `.then().catch()`.

```js
// симуляция первой асинхронной функции
function get_avg_value() {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return res('hello');
    }, 1000);
  })
};

// симуляция второй асинхронной функции
function get_another_value() {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return res('world');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

// функция, которая должна идти после них
function import_to_json(val) {
  console.log(val);
}

// Ждем пока выполнятся асинхронные функции и тогда вызываем импорт_ту_джсон
Promise.all([get_avg_value(), get_another_value()]).then(res => {
  import_to_json(res);
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, углубился в тему и разобрался!

Comment: пожалуйста.....